# NullExceptionReference in Neo4jUsermanager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, neo4j, asp.net-web-api2, neo4jclient

I'm new at neo4j and I'm using neo4j.aspnet.identity for authenticaion and authorization. I'm also using neo4jUserStore and neo4jUsermanager but when I run application in create method in Neo4jUserManager class, NullException Reference occures,Anybody have any idea of how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please include a sample code and clear way to reproduce your problem.

Comment: when I want to register new user before CreateAsync method check if the email is unique but in this function I always have a null exception @adrin